# Test that rails helper renders a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Given the following helper method, how would I properly test this using `rspec`?

```
  def datatable(rows = [], headers = [])
    render 'shared/datatable', { :rows => rows, :headers => headers }
  end

  def table(headers = [], data = [])
    render 'shared/table', headers: headers, data: data
  end
```

I've tried the following but I get the error: `can't convert nil into String`

```
describe 'datatable' do
  it 'renders the datatable partial' do
    rows = []
    headers = []
    helper.should_receive('render').with(any_args)
    datatable(rows, headers)
  end
end
```

**Rspec Output**

```
Failures:

  1) ApplicationHelper datatable renders the datatable partial
     Failure/Error: datatable(rows, headers)
     TypeError:
       can't convert nil into String
     # ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:26:in `datatable'
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:45:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**./app/helpers/application_helper.rb:26**

```
render 'shared/datatable', { :rows => rows, :headers => headers }
```

**views/shared/_datatable.html.haml**

```
= table headers, rows
```

**views/shared/_table.html.haml**

```
%table.table.dataTable
  %thead
    %tr
      - headers.each do |header|
        %th= header
  %tbody
    - data.each do |columns|
      %tr
        - columns.each do |column|
          %td= column
```

Comment: Which line is yielding this error?

Comment: I've updated the question w/ some additional details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you just want to test that your helper calls the right partial with the correct parameters you can do the following:

```
describe ApplicationHelper do

  let(:helpers) { ApplicationController.helpers }

  it 'renders the datatable partial' do
    rows    = double('rows')
    headers = double('headers')

    helper.should_receive(:render).with('shared/datatable', headers: headers, rows: rows)

    helper.datatable(rows, headers)
  end

end
```

note that this won't call the actual code in your partial.

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `should_receive` should be a symbol instead of string. At least I have not seen string is used in doc(https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations)

So, instead of

```
helper.should_receive('render').with(any_args)
```

Use this

```
helper.should_receive(:render).with(any_args)
```

Not sure if this could solve the problem but at least this is an error which cause your error message probably.

Comment: I tried using a symbol but am still getting the error. Good to know that I should only use symbols though!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
describe 'datatable' do
  it 'renders the datatable partial' do
    rows = []
    headers = []
    helper.should_receive(:render).with(any_args)
    helper.datatable(rows, headers)
  end
end
```

The helper spec documentation explains this:
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec

The error message is very confusing, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

here you have a problem of convertion

> can't convert nil into String

you pass an 2 empty arrays as parameters to the function, but empty array in ruby is not nil, then parameters of render should be a string, not sure but try to convert parameters in your test to string like this :

```
datatable(rows.to_s, headers.to_s)
```

Comment: But these parameters need to be array's because I'm looping over them inside of the partial.